# Connect an onload function with an onresize function

Tags: javascript, api, width, onload, onresize

I want to shorten some  API titles depending on the size of the screen. So I have an onload function to fetch and display the content of the API but I want an onresize function to act live any moment the size of the screen width changes.

```
window.onload = function displayNews(width){
   fetch('some api url')
   .then(res => {
      return (res.json())
   })
   .then(function(res) {
    let postsArr = res.data.children;

    for (let i = 0; i < postsArr.length; i++) {
      let currPost = postsArr[i].data;
      let currPostTitle = currPost.title;

      if (width > 1525) {
         currPostTitle = currPostTitle.substring(0, 100) + '&hellip;';
      } else if (width < 1525 && width > 1090) {
         currPostTitle = currPostTitle.substring(0, 20) + '&hellip;';
      } else if (width < 1090) {
         currPostTitle = currPostTitle.substring(0, 200) + '&hellip;';
      }

      let markup = 
      `
      //(Some API display)
```

Then I created the onresize function that passes the width variable to the onload function

```
window.onresize = function windowWidth() {
   let width = $(window).width();
   displayNews(width);
}
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know where to place the onresize function. I've tried to place it within the onload one but maybe I made a mistake. What do you think?

Comment: you want to execute `fetch()` everytime the window resize?

Comment: I think I just want to execute it one time. But I want the title for the post I'm extracting it from to shorten or enlarge when the size of the screen changes.